# Bind allow zone transfer from NS IPs defined in zone files

Tags: linux, ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

I am Setting up a Bind Server and am migrating the zone files from a Windows Server 2003 that used to be the DNS Server in charge.
(I'm running `Bind 9.9.5` on `Ubuntu 14.04 LTS`)

On the Windows Server it was possible, to use the NS Records in the zone files as the allowed IPs which were able to transfer zones.

Is it possible to do this in Bind as well? Or can the allowed addresses only be defined in the config files with `allow-transfer { 1.2.3.4; };`?

In the zone files, the name servers are defined like this:

```
;
;  Zone NS records
;

@                       NS      ns1.example.org.
ns1.example.org.      A       1.2.3.3
@                       NS      ns2.example.org.
ns2.example.org.      A       5.6.7.8
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there is no option in BIND to automatically use the addresses associated the zone's `NS` names for `allow-transfer`.

The [`allow-transfer`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#access_control) option is documented like this:

> **allow-transfer**
>
> Specifies which hosts are allowed to receive zone transfers from the
>   server. allow-transfer may also be specified in the zone statement, in
>   which case it overrides the options allow-transfer statement. If not
>   specified, the default is to allow transfers to all hosts.

The syntax is simply:

```
[ allow-transfer { address_match_list }; ]
```

An [`address_match_list`](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#address_match_lists) element allows for matching based on individual IP addresses, IP prefixes (prefix/length notation), [ACLs](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2574009) or [TSIG keys](http://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.ch06.html#id2574789).

Defining an ACL (essentially a named `address_match_list`) may be preferable, depending on your situation (for one thing the ACL can be referenced in many places).
When feasible TSIG is generally a better option for access control than simply allowing access based on client IP address.

Comment: It should be noted however that BIND *will* automatically send NOTIFY messages to the servers listed in the apex `NS` records. This can result in secondaries sending spurious notifies to each other which will generate unnecessary logged warnings. This can be disabled by specifying `notify explicit;` in the individual zone definitions or the global options.

Answer (score 1):

Notice of NS records simply points to other servers/clients to which servers to handle requests for a particular zone.
You can not specify allow-transfer, the default is to allow transfers to all hosts. It`s unsecure and can lead to significant load on the server.
In other words, NS record is just about information.
Allow-transfer option specifies permissions.